# How do you pronounce "bald"?

Tags: pronunciation

I've always heard it pronounced /bɒld/ (rhymes with scald, for those of you who don't know IPA), however the dictionary and some of my friends say /bɔ:ld/ (rhymes with mauled). I'm British, by the way. Any insights? Please say where you're from with your answer.

Comment: mauled, bald, scald all have the same vowel (as in mauled) where I come from (US Upper Midwest by way of US East Coast).  If I'm interpreting the IPA correctly, you're saying "bald" rhymes with "dolled" in your neck of the woods.

Comment: There are British speakers who don't rhyme *bald* and *skald*? I regularly learn something new from this site. (Of course, Brits will probably be equally surprised that there are Americans who don't rhyme *cog* and *log*.)

Comment: @PeterShor Which parts of the US? Which one do they pronounce "weird" (i.e. not rhyming with *hog*, *slog*, *bog*, *dog*, etc).

Comment: @Dan: *cog* is different, while all the others rhyme. They'll rhyme any place where Americans pronounce *cot* and *caught* the same. But I think the difference is widespread in areas which don't have the *cot/caught* merger. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cog) says that *cog* should be pronounced with the vowel of *cot*, while in the Northeast the most common pronunciation of *dog*, by far, is with the vowel of *caught*.

Comment: Ach, my apologies, I'm from the north of England, we pronounce scald, dance, grass, etc. differently than the south ('a' as in cat) .That might explain where I'm getting it from! When I say bald/scald,  it's the same as the 'al' in alternative.

Comment: @PeterShor Hm. I pronounce *cot* and *caught* differently, but still rhyme *cog* with all the others.

Comment: @Matt: I have definitely heard people pronounce *cog* both ways (rhyming and not rhyming with *dog*), Merriam-Webster notwithstanding. So your pronunciation isn't uncommon.

Comment: With an 'o' as in dog: halt,  vault, false, golf, doll, dolled. With 'or' as in torn: walk, sort

Comment: @Dan my wife who is from Solihull pronounces the vowel sound in *bald, bold* and *bowled* all in exactly the same way. I have no idea sometimes what she is saying.

Comment: @Charl E, I feel for you, must be a struggle to understand!

Comment: @Renoized isn't the 'a' of cat the /æ/ of /kæt/?

Comment: @CharlE: it's standard to pronounce "bold" and "bowled" the same way. Do you pronounce them differently? How so?

Comment: @sumelic: differently albeit not much. *Bold* has a short vowel sound; *bowled* has a longer sound, and with a definite, if slight, pursed-lips 'w' at the end of it. Of course if I were a stage actor or a news reader it would be more emphasised but there's always a difference. The W is there for a reason! My accent is faint English South African modified by elocution lessons and 25 years of living in Oxford so is probably pretty neutral and close to standard modern RP. I do a lot of speaking to audiences as part of my job.

Comment: @CharlE: what about "rolled"; does it rhyme with "bowled" for you? (And "roll" presumably rhymes with "bowl"?)

Comment: @sumelic: no. *rolled* has the same sound as *bold*. Short 'o' sound. As in *cold*, *fold* etc. *Bowled* has the longer vowel.

Comment: @CharlE: that's surprising. What about *foal* and *foaled*?

Comment: @sumelic: I had to think about that. If I were reading out loud and had to say *foaled* I would make an effort to distinguish it from the way I say *fold* by slightly lengthening the vowel sound to suggest the dipthong. I doubt I've ever used the word in conversation. (I think a great deal of the characteristics of accents disappear when reading out loud and concentrating on the sound one is making.)

Comment: [Nobody cares how YOU pronounce it](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/6603/nobody-cares-how-you-pronounce-it). A valid question would be, how do I pronounce [word] in [this specific] English dialect. Asking how *bald* is pronounced in all of the 100+ dialects is way too broad IMO.

Comment: I can't speak for anyone else, but here's [*Emma Saying* it on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I9dGeDMYXHg). It's close enough IMO to the only non-accented dialect of English that I know of: 'newspeak' (the broadcasting accent, not Orwell's *1984*).

Answer (score 6):

The pronunciation of "bald" as /bɔ:ld/ is older. What seems to have happened historically for some speakers of British English is phonemic shortening of the sound /ɔ:/ to /ɒ/ in some cases when it comes before a consonant cluster /lC/ (where C stands for any consonant). This change, and the resulting variation in pronunciation, is described in the following post on John Wells's phonetic blog: [scolding water](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2010/02/scolding-water.html). Here is the relevant paragraph:

> It is well known that words like *salt* can have either **ɔː** or **ɒ**.
>   Although I have continued to prioritize **ɔː** in LPD I have to confess
>   that the most recent poll I did on *salt* showed a sharp trend of change
>   over time in the direction of **ɒ**. The youngest age group voted 71% for
>   the LOT vowel. Only 34% of my own age group voted that way, which
>   accounts for my bias in favour of THOUGHT in this and similar words
>   (i.e. words in which the vowel is followed by l and a voiceless
>   consonant — *alter, false, fault, waltz* etc.). Where the consonant
>   after the lateral is voiced I believe there is less variation.
>   Nevertheless I recall that my mother pronounced scald as **skɒld**, which
>   was odd because she had the expected **ɔː** in *bald, alder* etc. (Why, even
>   as a child, did I think her pronunciation of *scald* was odd?)

I also found this Livejournal post about it: [scolding slurry](http://zuzentzailea.livejournal.com/4634.html), which suggests that it is connected to the loss of the LOT-CLOTH split in most modern forms of standard British English. Apparently, another environment where shortening occured was in words like *austere* (listed as having the CLOTH vowel /ɒ/ by the [British Library](http://www.bl.uk/learning/langlit/sounds/case-studies/received-pronunciation/vowel-sounds-rp/)). This shortening is further discussed in this article by Piotr Gąsiorowski: [*The History of [ɔː]: Is There Regular Orthographically Conditioned Sound Change?*](http://www.academia.edu/1504190/The_History_of_%C9%94%CB%90_Is_There_Regular_Orthographically_Conditioned_Sound_Change); Gąsiorowski mentions a few more words with exceptional /ɒ/ such as *sausage, laurel* and *cauliflower*. I'm not sure if any American dialects that maintain a distinction between the vowels of COT and CAUGHT show the effects of such shortening in *salt* and related words; it seems to be mainly a British phenomenon.

It appears that your dialect shows shortening of /ɔ:l/ before voiced consonants as well, such as /d/. But this does not apply before the secondary cluster /ld/ formed when verbs that end in /ɔ:l/ are followed by the past suffix /d/. (There are attested sound changes with conditions like this in some other dialects of English, such as the [Scottish vowel length rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_vowel_length_rule#Vowel_length) or the distinction between words like [freeze/frees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_high_front_vowels#Other_changes) and [bruise/brews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_high_back_vowels#Other_changes) in Geordie.)

So for you not only *halt, vault, false, alternative* /hɒlt/ /vɒlt/ /fɒls/ /ɒlt.../, but also *bald, scald* /bɒld/ /scɒld/ have the same vowel as *golf, doll, dolled* /gɒlf/ /dɒl/ /dɒld/. But *walk, maul, mauled*  /wɔ:k/ /mɔ:l/ /mɔ:ld/ have the same /ɔ:/ as *torn, sort*: they were not shortened because the first one lacks a pronounced /l/, the second one lacks a consonant after the /l/, and the third one has a consonant cluster only across morpheme boundaries.

The Oxford English dictionary (OED) lists alternative pronunciations with /ɒl/ instead of /ɔ:l/ for *halt, vault, false, fault*; but not for *bald* and *scald.* This fits with what Wells says about most speakers only having shortening before clusters of l + a voiceless consonant. However, there also seems to be some word-by-word variation, as in the case of Wells's mother.

Unfortunately, there's not a huge amount of evidence for the outcome of words with /ɔ:l/ followed by a voiced consonant, because I can't find any other common words that end with *auld*/*ald*. But here are some test words with this sound in the middle of a word; I'd be interested in knowing how you (or any other British English speakers) pronounce them:

- cauldron (OED only lists /ɔ:l/)
- alder/alderman/alderwoman (OED lists /ɔ:l/ and /ɒl/)
- baldric (OED only lists /ɔ:l/)
- thraldom (OED only lists /ɔ:l/; I'd assume the morpheme juncture means no one uses /ɒl/)

This analysis is just based on your described pronunciations. I have no personal experience with this; I'm American with the COT-CAUGHT merger, so I have /ɑ/ in all of these words.

Comment: I'm a Brit, SSBE speaker. I have /ɒ/ in  [ *halt, vault, false, alternative*] as well as  [*doll*] and [*dolled*], but I have /ɔ:/ in [*bald*] as well as [*scald*]. However, many dictionaries give  /ɔ:/ for [*false*]. It wouldn't surprise me if there were a substantial number of people who say /ɒ/ in [*bald*]. I'll look it up in LPD tomorrow. Just off the top of my head, I can't think of any words which - I think - I or my SSBE peers here in London would pronounce /ɒld/ at the end, unless the /d/ was a suffix.

Comment: The problem with /ɒ/ in _bald_ and _scald_ is that it causes ambiguity in meaning because of the existence of _bold_ and _scold_. "He was a /bɒld/ man" - it really could be either if you don't know that the speaker favours /bɔ:ld/.

Comment: @TimDown: Well, that's only true for speakers that merge /oʊl/ into /ɒl/ in that context.