# Why is "archaic" pronounced uniquely? Is the sequence -ɪɪ- only found in this word?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, phonology, vowels

Before looking this word up, I have always rhymed it with *cake* i.e. /ɑːˈkeɪk/. But when I looked it up, it was actually /ɑː(r)ˈke**ɪɪ**k/ with the sequence of a similar vowel repeated consecutively: -**ɪɪ**-

I find it rather strange and while looking up its etymology, I found nothing convincing. Here is what Wikitionary has to say:

> From *archaism* (“ancient or obsolete phrase or expression”) or from French *archaïque*, ultimately from Ancient Greek *ἀρχαϊκός*

But none of its roots have -ɪɪ-. Is this sequence of the same vowel repeated consecutively unique to "archaic"? How did it come about?

Comment: I don't see how archaic is pronounced uniquely.....

Comment: Closely related: [Which words have a long vowel before the suffix -ic?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/317173/which-words-have-a-long-vowel-before-the-suffix-ic/317174#317174)

Comment: Mosaic. Prosaic. Voltaic.

Comment: Formulaic, algebraic.

Comment: There are two words of the form "voltaic"; the word  in "Voltaic languages" takes a capital,  the word meaning "pertaining to electricity in chemical action)", is not capitalized.

Comment: @LPH similarly *mosiac* (tiled artwork) and *Mosaic* (related to Moses)

Comment: "But none of its roots have -ɪɪ-." Both of your etymological sources contain an `ï`. Did you miss the diaeresis (¨)?

Comment: I'm afraid that my answer, in spite of its unbelievable success, is not satisfactory; the explanation, which I take as more or less obvious, could be justified by a mere coincidence, and a much more widely applicable rule would be the proper explanation. See for instance this [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/419834/asg), which seems to be much more relevant, and see also the important number of  -aic-ending words that are not from French origin and which are pronounced in the same way. (I did not check enough of them) I will therefore delete this answer.

Comment: Since I cannot delete this answer without first the removal of your acceptation, I am asking you to undo the accepting, which you should probably do without hesitation after you become aware of what I just explained to you. Sorry for the inconvenience that this might have caused you.

Comment: @LPH your answer still holds true! Don't worry ;-)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The standard pronunciation in British English is really /ɑːˈkeɪ ik/ (Longman Pronunciation Dictionary), and there is no alternative. The splitting of the digraph into two phonemes is understandable as a remnant of the initial pronunciation intended to preserve the French ([aʀkaik]); in the French pronunciation  /ai/ is not a diphthong, but two separate sounds.

The sequence /-**ɪ**.**ɪ**-/ is also found in other words:

- voltaic, hebraic, mosaic (French), prosaic (French)

Comment: Nice! I had a vague memory of seeing -ɪɪ- in another word (which, if I recall correctly, was "prosaic") but couldn't come up with it until now.

Comment: From your answer, I suspect French /a/ corresponds to English /eɪ/. Am I right?

Comment: @Sphinx Exact, and "i" in /ɑːˈkeɪ ik/ corresponds to a choice that you can make between /ɪ/ (the regular sound of i in "fit", "lit", "tilt", etc. and a shortened form of the sound of "ee", as in "lead" (but short) (which amounts to the French i sound.

Comment: Thanks! I slightly modified your answer but you can revert it if you want. ;-)

Comment: @Sphinx No, but to be more precise,  the sequence is not a strict succession: there is a separation, that  is a very short silence that corresponds to syllabification.

Comment: Does ribonucleic count?

Comment: @Davo The combination "ei" in "nucleic" corresponds to /i: i/ or (traditional) /i: ɪ/.

Comment: "Oh, yeah, in the States, we pronounce is so differently", she sniped sarcastically. I wish people would stop constantly saying British English when it is **irrelevant**.

Comment: @Lambie It is not irrelevant at all: in Am E there is an r sound for the digraph "ar" in "archaic".

Comment: The difference is in the initial a sound but is not relevant to way she posed the question.

Comment: @Lambie The OP is not mentioning British English. By "uniquely" I thought they  meant "the only one word in the lexicon to have this pronunciation", don't you?

Comment: @LPH: I can't believe that you used "lead" as a guide to pronunciation! Is it the lead that rhymes with dead, or the lead that rhymes with bead?

Comment: Right, you are mentioning it. :) I think the issue is with the **aic**, and both BrE and AmE pronounce that the same way is all I am saying.

Comment: fyi, "ai" is a single sound in French, so we use a tréma to cause the two vowels to be pronounced independently: archaïque. More well known are "naïve" and "Noël".

Comment: The problem is that while French uses a tréma consistently, English (being English) does not use a diaeresis (those same two dots) very consistently at all.  Confusing things, the diaeresis is used in some contexts.  The _New Yorker's_ style guide mandates it (so you end up with words like _coördinate_ when you read the New Yorker): https://www.newyorker.com/culture/culture-desk/the-curse-of-the-diaeresis

Comment: @TonyK: LPH didn't mean the "lead" that rhymes with "read", but the "lead" that rhymes with "read".

Comment: @TonyK Your comment went by unnoticed, saw it just now. I probably figured that "lead" being meant to reinforce the evocation of the sound as that of "ee" (which is never /e/ and quite regularly /i:/), "lead" would be understood as in "to lead the way".

Comment: Also: algebraic, choleraic, deltaic, formulaic, paradisaic, Ptolemaic, Sabbathaic, Sadducaic, zebraic and many many others (85 total in the count I did).

Answer (score 16):

In English, there's a phoneme commonly called "long A" (because it evolved from what used to be a lengthened /a:/). This part's pretty uncontroversial: it's the phoneme in the middle of "face".

However, linguists have different views on how to transcribe this sound. It's often pronounced as a diphthong, so some people write it as /eɪ/, /ei/, or /ej/; other people just write it as /e/ for simplicity, and say it's fundamentally a single unit. This mostly comes down to a transcription convention. One standard way to talk about it (in a purely English context), without committing to any particular transcription, is "FACE" or "the FACE vowel".

In the word "archaic", the underlying phonemes in question are this "long A" (the FACE vowel) followed by "short I" (the KIT vowel). Some people transcribe this as /eɪ.ɪ/ or the like. But for me, I certainly don't pronounce the same vowel twice in a row: the off-glide of FACE is higher than the vowel in KIT. So I prefer to transcribe it instead as /ejɪ/, to emphasize this height difference.

The same sequence appears in a lot of words, when a suffix starting with KIT is attached to a root ending in FACE: others have mentioned "mosaic" and its ilk, but it also shows up in "laying" and so on.

P.S. As for how it happened: note the diaeresis in the Greek ἀρχαϊκός, indicating two separate vowels /a.i/ with a syllable break between them. When it was eventually borrowed into English (via Latin and French), this was how it was pronounced; later sound changes turned /a/ into /ej/ and /i/ into /ɪ/.

Comment: This answer best addresses the part of the question “But none of its roots have -ɪɪ-. Is **this sequence of the same vowel repeated consecutively** unique to ‘archaic’?” There really isn’t a sequence of two [ɪ] vowels; the fact that the IPA contains consecutive ɪ’s is an artefact of the “transcription convention” used to represent the vowel “long A.”

Comment: Personally, I think using /ej/ implies that you have the /j/ consonant, so would sound like A-yick. I think it's a situation where you need that syllable break to make it clear that the /j/ is just the offglide of a diphthong, making it /ej.ɪ/

Answer (score 5):

This should be a comment, but it wont let me make a comment.
In elementary American english grammar rules, a vowel followed by another vowel, or a vowel followed by a consonant by another vowel is a long vowel.  pronounce it as three syllables: ar + cha (long a) + ic (short i).  which is indicated in the pronunciation representation "-keIIk" spelling (same vowel-vowel rule).  The a in the middle syllable is long because it is immediately followed by another vowel.

Comment: Yes, but "ai" is usually pronounced as a single vowel (the diphthong /ej/). Here, it isn't, and that is what's causing the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Just to be clear.  The base Greek Word is *αρχη*, pronounced *archi* - but the 'ch' is like a guttural 'h', meaning *beginning* or *origin*.  The adjectives formed from it are *αρχαιος* (pronounced *archayos*) and *αρχαyϊκος* (with the 'i' separately pronounced).  They differ slightly in meaning.  The former means ancient or old; the latter has the overtone of 'out of date', particularly in the sense of the use of an antique form of a language for some sort of literary effect ('archaïsing').  Matters are all the trickier because the mediaeval scholars had some pretty strange ways of pronouncing the ancient Greek, as did I as a school boy.  The authentic pronunciation of the original words  (which differed regionally, just as English does) was only fully established in the latter third of the last century.

Comment: You have a Latin "y" mixed in with the Greek letters in  αρχαyϊκος.

Comment: @BenCrowell Yes, it was a crude attempt to convey how it would be pronounced!

Comment: The pronuncation of the Greek original is (almost) irrelevant - and, by the way, in Classical Greek, χ was an aspirated /k/, not a "guttural h". That is a later development.